# Does any DAG can be topologically sorted?

Tags: graph-theory, sorting, topological-graph-theory

I am not good enough in computer science. My intention is to solve some programming problem in terms of DAG's. **The key point** is that before getting them into database, I need run "topological sort" in order to guarantee an absence of cycles.

Hence, my questions:
1) Does any DAG can be topologically sorted? Is that a theorem? If yes, what's a common name for that?
2) Could any non-DAG be topological sorted as well? Can't I get into trouble relying **only** on such a sorting? If yes, then what is a better way to a) ensure there are no cycles at all, b) build a proper "string" such that for any pair of verticies A, B either A < B or B < A?

Comment: Any DAG with no cycle can be sorted according to the topological sorting algorithm.

Comment: Do you mean to ask what would happen if one runs a topological sort on a directed graph _with_ cycles?  If so, please edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAG stands for directed **acyclic** graph. Therefore no cycles. By applying topological sort you **won't "uncycle" the cyclic graph**. DAG has **no cycles**. This link may be interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph#Topological_ordering

The idea behind topological order is that node i is placed after all of it's dependencies. By applying topological sort you find an order, which doesn't violate parent/child dependency. Think of it as requirements to a course at university. You should do algorithms course (C), only when you've done discrete structures(A) and linear algebra (B), whereby A and B are not connected. So C should not appear before A and B in the sorted topological order. Obviously A-B-C and B-A-C is a valid order, since C is not encountered before A or B.